# Converting 'device units' to pixels?

Tags: c++, winapi, pixel

For the documentation for `CreateWindow` it says the width/height are specified in *"device units"* but I'd like to specify this in pixels. How can I do this?

Comment: They're probably the same thing. What size do you get if you make a window that is 500 by 500 device units?

Comment: It's just weird actually. I'm creating two child windows. One's a list-box and the other's just a window. Both have borders. At a height of 500, they appear the same height. When I set both of their heights to 540, the list-box appears shorter for some reason.

Comment: You can look into the [mapping mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162980.aspx), [viewport origin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145099.aspx) and [viewport extent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145098.aspx), which essentially control the relationship with pixels and device units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I set both of their heights to 540, the list-box appears shorter for some reason.

By design.  Use the LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT style flag if you want the listbox the have the exact programmed height.